# move image to center in popup modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am using a Popup modal component from the reactjs-popup library. I want to place the charts image (three charts in 1 image) at the center of the popup but properties like align-self dont seem to work for me. What else can I try?

```
export default () => (
  <Popup
    trigger={<button className="button"> Guide </button>}
    modal
    nested
  >
    {(close: any) => (
      <div className="modal">
        <button className="close" onClick={close}>
          &times;
        </button>
        <div className="header"> Guide </div>
        <div className="content">
          {' '}
          {/* <img src={chart} alt="charts" className="charts"/> */}
          <img src={img} alt="charts" className="charts" />
          What is overfitting?
          <br />
          What is underfitting?
          This example demonstrates the problems of underfitting and overfitting and how we can use linear regression with polynomial features to approximate nonlinear functions.
        </div>
        <div className="actions">
        </div>
      </div>
    )}
  </Popup>
);
```

This is how it looks like:
[image]

css

```
.modal {
    font-size: 12px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
  }
  .modal > .content {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    background-color: white;
  }
  .modal > .actions {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
  }
  .charts {
    align-self: center;
  }
```

I also want to move the text `what's overfitting` under the images in center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: flex;` to the css class of `.modal > content`. Furthermore, to align the items in the center, you need to set `flex-direction: column;` and `align-items: center` in the same css class.

I also recommend you read up on the concept of flex alignment in this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex).

Comment: I added these but then the popup window stretched to the full screen, image moved to left and text moved to right :(

Comment: Right, can you try using `flex-direction: column;` and `align-items: center` instead of justify-content?

I am 100% sure this is possible using flex box layout, so maybe you can figure it out yourself using the linked resources (or others)